# SQL most frequent values depending on another value

Tags: sql, oracle, group-by

I'm using SQL*Plus and i need some help. I have 1 table with tons of information of different cars with different drivers.

What i want to find is **the most frequent driver for each car plate**. I have the `CAR_PLATE` and `DRIVER` values. I've been trying to use `group by` and `count`, but I haven't been able to do it.

```
TEBLE (
..OTHER VALUES
DRIVER
CAR_PLATE
)
```

The data in it adds tons of different cars with different drivers but some repeat.

Comment: It's very hard to understand a question phrased like that. Please share you tables structure, some sample data and the result you'd like to get from that sample.

Answer (score 0):

> the most frequent driver for each car plate

This tells you that you need to group by `CAR_PLATE` and need the count of `DRIVER`. Since you need the count of `DRIVER` driver also needs to be in the `group by` clause. 
Since you want the most frequent one, you will also need to `order by` on the count.

```
SELECT
  CAR_PLATE,
  DRIVER,
  count(DRIVER) AS driver_count
FROM tableName
GROUP BY CAR_PLATE, DRIVER
ORDER BY driver_count DESC;
```

Here is an SQL fiddle to play with: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/d08ea/4